# how to upload a folder on Kaggle Notebook

Tags: kaggle

I am using Kaggle for the very first time and I want to upload a folder on Kaggle from my local system like:
/kaggle/working/MyFolder

Answer (score 0):

#### Just drag and drop the folder like this

[image: image info]

[source](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/product-feedback/113250)